# Сохранение значений input-ов в localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, localstorage

Есть 3 инпута, надо сохранить их значения в `localStorage`. Все три поля не может сохранить почему-то:

```js
var txt = document.getElementById("1");
txt.value = localStorage["1"] || "";
window.go = function() {
  localStorage["1"] = txt.value;
}
var txt = document.getElementById("2");
txt.value = localStorage["2"] || "";
window.go = function() {
  localStorage["2"] = txt.value;
}
var txt = document.getElementById("3");
txt.value = localStorage["3"] || "";
window.go = function() {
  localStorage["3"] = txt.value;
}
```

```html
<input id="1">
<input id="2">
<input id="3">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Сохранение и получение значений из `localStorage` реализуется с помощью методов [setItem](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) и [getItem](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem)
2. Сохранять значения input-ов имеет смысл при их изменении, то есть при срабатывании события `change`

Пример реализации:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var ids = ["1", "2", "3"];
  for (var id of ids) {
    var input = document.getElementById(id);
    input.value = localStorage.getItem(id);
    (function(id, input) {
      input.addEventListener("change", function() {
        localStorage.setItem(id, input.value);
      });
    })(id, input);
  } 
});
```

[Полный пример в JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dq4ytvcb/9/)